# What are the ContextualActionView of the ActionBar for?

Tags: python, kivy

From the name, I was expecting that there was a way to change the context of the `ActionBar` and display a `ContextualActionView` view accordingly. All I can find in the documentation [is the following](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.actionbar.html#kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionView):

> The `ActionBar` will contain one ActionView and many
>   `ContextualActionView`s. (...) A `ContextualActionView` is a subclass of
>   an `ActionView`.

There also seem to be a [Kivy context](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.context.html), but the documentation is scarce as well.